# Calculating number of characters in a line in a character array

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I'm trying to write a program that finds strings in a character array and output the strings randomly as well as output string number and length. The trouble I seem to be having is picking out the length. I'm not sure if I should use the length stored in the comment (if it can even do that) or count each character and output the length that way. I'm not really sure how to do that though.

```
char * strings [] ={

// String 1 of 5000:  Length = 185
"J1{GW3_%-3s_%p*E<ed<qLB#YHN%S8.odr5|[QPz&Hslk#3vi[)T3wgh3lHdVtTGz|M1RsGy_r=J]Rgp`0+s)pbvpm<u'8NsPX:Uk)kU,d5t@w[{2efjt*z_`eOqa#iP3z)T<(eYWb%W{5g?ynp*<jfEeLUA5:ukgvw$Le,Yjv*o{a/,tV#dG1|+D", 

// String 2 of 5000:  Length = 9
"^PuU]gjh)", 

}
```

Right now I'm using a rand function to output 5,000 strings to an output file like so

```
outfile1 << strings[rand()%5000] << endl;
```

This function is nested within a loop and it seems to output it randomly, but it's the same random pattern every time, so maybe I should seed the rand function differently.

Anyway, I really am lost when it comes to showing the length of each string in the output file. Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I can do this? This is homework so I'd like some information on how to apply this rather than a straight answer. :)

As of now my output is this:

```
#11 (Length:168) - JZn'TGF&#K=EohoZT
#12 (Length:189) - DiF9ao^T,7rtQ#Yc>n{_YIG_y
#13 (Length:50) - y,|l2;hA;H;pHz?|jLADh
```

As you can see, the strings output correctly but the length is incorrect.

Comment: Why can't you extract the string and use `string::size()` or simple `strlen()` ?

Comment: I'm looking into both of those now and trying to figure out how to apply it here. :)

Comment: Can you let us know the exact wording of your homework question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

///Updated answer//

I think what you want to do is to output each string in the array and calculate each of their length right??? I wrote this quick program and it worked fine.

```
char* strings[] = {"hellothisistom", "nicetomeetyou"};

for (int i = 0; i<2; i++)
{
    int k = rand()%2;
    cout<< strings[k] << endl;
    cout<< strlen(strings[k])<<endl;

}
```

You can replace cout with your output file string.
Make sure you use the same `k` to get both the string and the length!

////////////////////////////////////////////////

A *character* is a one-bit character such as 'A', 'b', '%', etc.
A *character string* is simply an array of characters.
On the other hand, a *string* is a special class that represent a series of characters.

*Character String*, works like a normal array. 
In your case, the `strings` (which is a character array), you can just use `sizeof(strings)/sizeof(strings[0])` to find out the number of characters.

As you mentioned, that character string is made up of many short strings. Unless there are some special characters that separate the words, there is no way (at least not easy way) to separate the string of characters into words.

For example if your character string is `hellothisistom`. There is no way to separate the words... unless you go into natural language processing.
If your character string is like `hello/this/is/tom`, which there is some thing that separates individual words, then you can use many kinds of methods to extracts the words. You can check out the site below for the tools that you can use. 
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/

For example, in a loop you can search for the first occurrence of that special character and search for the one after that. Then you just copy the characters in between, output those characters and and size (using that method mentioned above). Then move on to the next one.

When you output `stings[rand()%5000]`, won't there be just a bunch of random characters inside `strings`?

Comment: My output file lists each of the "strings" without quotes in random order and of course, skips comments. That part works fine. I've done sizeof already and it shows that the array itself is made up of 5000 lines. Actually I was experimenting and used "     outfile1 << strlen(strings[rand()%5000]);" and it ended up doing what I wanted it to do in terms of showing the lengths, however it's arbitrary and doesn't show the length I asked for (for example a string of 30 characters shows it as 57) most likely because of the rand function, but I think I'm getting close!

Comment: I don't think it is actually doing what you wanted to do.
How did you initiate the string?? According to what you posted, `char* strings[] = {....} ` would not work! If you try to output those characters, it will just be random values (not those that you created) as they are memory space that are not yet allocated.
Check out this site for how to properly instantiate a character array. 
http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/ntcs/
Why don't you try experiment with a short string array that you know what's in it first?

Comment: I think I may have mislead you with my description. Check it again please, maybe it'll make more sense now. My code has 5,000 lines of that and they all output perfectly with the rand function. How? I do not know, but it does indeed work after much testing. I feel like I'm learning in fragments which is definitely not good lol, but I am learning.

Comment: Sorry my mistake. `char* strings[] = {...} is fine.
I think I get what you are trying to do now. You have an array of strings and try to output the string and the number of characters in each strings right??

Comment: Right, exactly. Sorry, I've been up for a long time and I might not quite get my words right, haha. I used the rand function on strlen() for kicks and that's why it's giving me the arbitrary string length number. I feel like I could be doing something else, but I'm just still not quite sure of it.

Comment: Haha, not sure what timezone you are at. I guess it must be really late in where you are....

Check out my updated answer... see if that answer your question!

Comment: I'll give it a shot, thanks. :) Nope, not super late, I've just been up for a long time!

Comment: This works very well, I understand it a lot more now, thank you. Now I just need to figure out how to randomize them, but I can probably do that with a nested loop or something similar... hmm.

Comment: I think maybe... you use a different index when you try to output the length and output the string??
`cout<<strings[rand()%5000]<<", "strlen(strings[rand()%5000])<<endl;` won't work because the two "rand()%5000" are not the same.

Comment: I see, yeah. I think I'm getting a bit closer. I tried a few more things but I think it's time for me to sleep. Thank you very much, I'll try more of this tomorrow. :)

Answer (score 0):

What's the problem that you'd ultimately solve, are you trying to parse data ?

I don't understand this 'finds strings in a character array and output the strings randomly'; You must know that a char array can be comprehended as a giant string, so are you looking for special delimiters and you want to return a list of all the valid matches ?

If so, how do you tell the difference between a valid string and random stuff in the source; should it be delimited ?

How can you output strings randomly ?

Please add some more detail about what you're trying to solve and the data you're working on.

Comment: Yes, as this data is in a character array when I say "string" I mean a string of random characters as shown above. I'm not sure if using string::size() or any other variation would work when I'm using a character array, so perhaps using a delimiter like you said would make more since. My program would need to count the characters in-between the quotes and spit it out for each output. That particular piece is what I'm having the most trouble with.

Answer (score 0):

str.size() where str is your string variable will output the length of the string

Answer (score 0):

1. > srand(time(0));

The standard way to generate decent pseudo-random numbers. 'srand' specifies a seed based on the number passed in the function, while 'time(0)' will return different number every second, so this should fix your 'same pattern' issue.

1. a) You can use [strlen](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strlen/)

   b) Or you can simply write a function that will go through the string checking each character for 0 (0 - end of the line) and then returning the current iteration value.

Comment: I'll play around with seeding in a bit. I've done it before but not for a while. Thanks. :)

Comment: Yep, it worked great. Thank you. Still working on my other problem though but I'm getting there!